# Multiple test case execution: I want to wait for page load in selenium in java

Tags: selenium

I need help for selenium to wait for entire page load, when executing the test cases.

Wait time is to be defined in milliseconds for each step. It will be good if  we have better way of doing it (like wait till page loading is complete). please give me some  answers.

Answer (score 2):

Something along the lines of the following code should give what you desire. Do this after instantiating your driver but before finding the elements (In the SetUp methods preferably).

```
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Comment: hi paul  need information more.beacuse already i used  implicitlywait at elements level. but i want enter wait page load level.

Comment: You just do this when initializing the driver to accomplish it throughout the instance of the driver.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the ultimate solution specifically when you are dealing with Angular 7 or 8.

Instead of waiting for a longer duration using sleep or implicit wait methods, you can divide your wait time into the partition and use it recursively.

Below logic will wait for the page to render for a minimum of 300 seconds and a maximum of 900 seconds.

```
/**
 * This method will check page loading
 *
 */
public void waitForLoadingToComplete() {
    waitLoadingTime(3); // Enter the number of attempts you want to try
}

 private void waitLoadingTime(int i) {
        try {
  // wait for the loader to appear after particular action/click/navigation
            this.staticWait(300); 
  // check for the loader and wait till loader gets disappear
            waitForElementToBeNotPresent(By.cssSelector("Loader Element CSS"));                                                             
        } catch (org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException e) {
            if (i != 0)
                waitLoadingTime(i - 1);
        }
    }

/**
 * This method is for the static wait
 *
 * @param millis
 */
public void staticWait(final long millis) {
    try {
        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(millis);
    } catch (final InterruptedException e) {
        System.err.println("Error in staticWait." + e);
    }
}

public void waitForElementToBeNotPresent(final By element) {
    long s = System.currentTimeMillis();
    new WebDriverWait(this.getDriver(), 30)
            .until(ExpectedConditions.not(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfAllElementsLocatedBy(element)));
    System.err.println("Waiting for Element to be not present completed. " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - s));
}
```